# Share a partial getopts as a function

Tags: shell, scripting, sh, posix

Say I have the following code in one place (a test runner):

```
while getopts ":s:t:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    s )
      if [ -z "$servers_under_test" ]
        then
          servers_under_test="${OPTARG}"
        else
          servers_under_test="${servers_under_test} ${OPTARG}"
      fi
      ;;
    t )
      type_of_test="${OPTARG:-'ci'}"
      ;;
    \? ) echo "Usage: cmd [-s] [-t]"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

and the following code in another (the server runner):

```
while getopts ":s:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    s )
      if [ -z "$servers_to_run" ]
        then
          servers_to_run="${OPTARG}"
        else
          servers_to_run="${servers_under_test} ${OPTARG}"
      fi
      ;;
    \? ) echo "Usage: cmd [-s]"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Is it possible for me to unify the shared element (the -s flag handler, obviously with a sensible variable name change) as a shared function in sh? Preferably in a POSIX compliant way?

Comment: The `s` case can be simplified to: `servers_under_test="${servers_under_test}${servers_under_test:+ }${OPTARG}"`

Comment: I'm guessing it'll be looped over later so a leading space doesn't matter, in which case it could just be `servers_to_run="$servers_to_run $OPTARG"`

Comment: You could certainly write a function, e.g. 
 `servers_under_test="$(append "$servers_under_test" "$OPTARG")"` or `append servers_under_test "$OPTARG"`. If that's something you want to do, I would suggest trying that and optionally posting about any issues you have in that process